# Similarities / suggestions of multi-attribute entities

Tags: machine-learning, similarities, graph-theory

**Dataset:**

- I have 200 000 entites, these have zero or more of 1000 attributes
  (commonly 1-20 of them)
- The attibute relation is weighted 1-3
- Its stored in a relational database modeles as Entity, Attribute,
  EntityAttrubuteRelation
- The data set has additions over time (neglible subtractions)

**Problem 1:** Given N attributes, what other attributes can i suggest based how much they appear together (on entities)? Ex: If all entities with attribute A, B, C also have attribute D and half have E. Querying for A, B, C would return D as top weighted and E as half weighted.

**Problem 2:** Given N weighted attributes, what entities have this set of attributes or fewer, in a ranked list? Weighted input means that the ranking should favor these attributes. Ex: Qeury for A, E in the example dataset in problem 1 should return all those entities, but score those matching both higher. Entity-attribute weight should also be taken into consideration.

I have very basic knowledge of mathematical concepts, machine learning and its notations, and may have mislabeled something above. Here are my approaches so far:

**Graph approach, problem 1**

An attempt could be an undirected weighted graph where the attributes are nodes, and edges are co-occurance frequency (normalized?). But with this i can "only" lookup a single attribute, and suggest other attributes based on this single one. This could possibly be done for all the N attributes in the problem and joined / ranked (?)

**Cosine similarity approach, problem 2**

An approach could be to query for entites that contain one or more of the N attributes. Plot each of the resulting entities into vector space based on the attribute weights [0,0,0,1,2,3,1,0,0...] and do a cosine similarity on them to rank them. Since the attributes are pretty sparse, i would only have to retrieve a small set of entites to do the calcs.
This approach could possibly be used for problem 1, where i count (?) and rank attributes from the resulting entities as suggestions

These problems seem related to me, is there a solution i can use for both? One Class Classifiation? Are there other obvious solutions im missing? Given the additive nature of the dataset i get the feeling that i should train some kind of model, that can provide my answers

Comment: Although the nature of your two problems is apparent, they need to be articulated less vaguely.  To make progress you need to be more specific and quantitative.  In the first problem, what is the purpose of "suggesting" attributes and what would be the basis for ranking suggestions?  In the second problem, how would you assess "similarity"?  Ordinarily the context and specific objectives of an application suggest answers to these questions, but since you have posed your problems abstractly, we do not have access to this essential information.  Could you include such information in the post?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I’m perhaps a bit sloppy with those words. Suggesting in P1 would be based on how often they occur together on other entities. In P2 similarities would be other entities with the same attributes. I’ve tried to clear it up in an edit, but not sure if it’s better